# How to get booking list with matching with users of any company in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

We have company and their users. We want to  get all booking list with users of a company.

Please suggest how can we solve this issue.

Let's something like this

```
$booking=Booking::with('users')->where()
```

In where like

```
users.company_id=$company_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```php
$company_id = 1;
$booking=Booking::with('users' => function ($query) use ($company_id) {
    $query->where('company_id', $company_id);
}])->get();
```

It's in [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), the name of this is "Constraining Eager Loads"